# PayFast URLs must be valid

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to implement PayFast into my ASP.NET MVC website. During testing on the sandbox environment. Everything worked fine, I was able to redirect a buyer to either the return or cancel URLs depending on their action done.

As soon as I used the live PayFast url, I get an error saying that my return, cancel and notify URLs must be valid. Are my urls wrong? Or is there something that I am missing?

These are my URLs that I used in both the sandbox and live environment:

```
<!-- Used in sandbox environment-->
<add key="ProcessUrl" value="https://sandbox.payfast.co.za/eng/process?" />
<add key="ValidateUrl" value="https://sandbox.payfast.co.za/eng/query/validate" />
<!-- Used in live environment-->
<add key="ProcessUrl" value="https://payfast.co.za/eng/process?" />
<add key="ValidateUrl" value="https://payfast.co.za/eng/query/validate" />
<!--Return, Cancel and Notify URLS-->
<add key="ReturnUrl" value="http://www.xxx.co.za/return" />
<add key="CancelUrl" value="http://www.xxx.co.za//cancel" />
<add key="NotifyUrl" value="http://www.xxx.co.za/notify" />
```

Any help will be much appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL for the live PayFast payment page is wrong. As per the [PayFast docs](https://developers.payfast.co.za/documentation/#getting-started), the live transacting URL is:
`https://www.payfast.co.za/eng/process`, note the `www`.

PayFast will perfrom a 301 redirect from:

`https://payfast.co.za/eng/process?`

To:

`https://www.payfast.co.za/eng/process`

When this redirect occurs, the posted values are lost, and the PayFast payment page will then throw an error.

Comment: It was indeed the live URL, the "?" was the problem. The "?" invoked a redirect within their API. This solved my issue. Thanks man. Appreciate it.